# No Battery Indicator in panel 12.04

Tags: indicator, power-management, battery

On ac power or battery power, I cannot get a battery status indicator to show in the 12.04 panel.

I have tried: 
1) Checked the Power Settings and battery is set to show all the time.

2) `sudo apt-get purge indicator-power` then `sudo apt-get install indicator-power`
  no change.

3) running `gnome-settings-daemon` and get:

"(gnome-settings-daemon:5514): GnomeDesktop-WARNING **: Timed out waiting for GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE helper

** (gnome-settings-daemon:5514): WARNING **: You can only run one xsettings manager at a time; exiting

** (gnome-settings-daemon:5514): WARNING **: Unable to start xsettings manager: Could not initialize xsettings manager.

** (gnome-settings-daemon:5514): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down

(gnome-settings-daemon:5514): print-notifications-plugin-CRITICAL **: gsd_print_notifications_plugin_finalize: assertion `plugin->priv != NULL' failed"

no change.

4) adding a detailed status indicator per instructions on http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/battery-applet-status-ubuntu/

no success as of yet.

I am good at following directions, but a n00b at searching out the root of problems.  This seems to be a fairly common one for 12.04 users, so any other solutions or help will greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For battery/power enter this command in terminal than logout and login back:
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true

Comment: I have the same problem in 12.10, but this didn't help.